# Validating a self association with the before_add callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, associations

I have a model `Todo` with self referential parents and children

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :children, class_name: "Todo", join_table: "todos_todos", foreign_key: "parent_id", association_foreign_key: :child_id
has_and_belongs_to_many :parents, class_name: "Todo", join_table: "todos_todos", foreign_key: "child_id", association_foreign_key: :parent_id
```

I want do something like `before_add` on both of them that will throw a validation error. I've tried `before_add: [:parent_due_after_or_on_self]` with

```
def parent_due_after_or_on_self(parent)
    if parent.due < self.due 
        self.errors.add(:parents, "Parent cannot be due before child")
    end 
end
```

But that does nothing. I've tried adding `raise "Parent cannot be due before child"` right after adding the error, and that gets me the error message, but now I can't rescue it to return the user to the form to fix their mistake. I'm *positive* I got this working earlier this week, but I've lost the code and can't remember what it was exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As @meagar♦ wrote in 
[Rails 4 HABTM custom validation on associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24559489/rails-4-habtm-custom-validation-on-associations), there is no valid way to use validations on HABTM associations.

In my opinion, the best option is to use `has_many :through =>`, and use your connecting model (in your case **TodosTodo**) for validations.

Comment: TodosTodos isn't another model, but just a join table. If I switch to something like `has_many :parents, class_name: "Todo", :through => TodosTodos` will I be able to perform validations on add like I want to?

Comment: Rails associations guide tells me "If a before_add callback throws an exception, the object does not get added to the collection". Couldn't I do this instead? Something like `raise "Parent not added"`?

Comment: First of all, you can create a TodosTodos model for the solution. with your solution you need to make the callback on the association arguments: `has_and_belongs_to_many :children, before_add: parent_due_after_or_on_self`, but adding errors won't help. you can raise and exception and catch it with an actual error on the adding method.